# I get "Invalid left-hand side in assignment" in my code (JS)

Tags: javascript

Im simply putting don't know why but this line gets an error that says "Invalid left-hand side in assignment". I've no idea why it's saying that for **this** line.

```
Div1.style.background-color = white;
```

*I temporarily change the colour of the div.

Any advice / fixes are greatly appreciated.

Comment: use `Div1.style.backgroundColor = white;` ... css properties containing `-` are accessed in javascript using camel cased version of the property ... eg, remove the `-` and capitalise the next letter

Answer (score 3):

use `Div1.style.backgroundColor = 'white';` - note the quotes around white - you need the quotes, unless of course you have a variable called `white` with a (valid) colour as a string, e.g. `var white = '#ffffff';`

css properties containing `-` are accessed in javascript using camel cased version of the property ... eg, remove the `-` and capitalise the next letter

so `text-align` becomes `textAlign`, `box-shadow` becomes `boxShadow` `-webkit-box-shadow` would become `WebkitBoxShadow` ... note the capital `W`

to explain the error, you wrote

```
Div1.style.background-color = white;
```

which is

```
Div1.style.background - color = white;
```

which is like saying

```
x - y = z;
```

which I hope you can see is not valid javascript syntax